# Using StringTokenizer with Comma delimiter while at the same time keeping commas preceded by a backslash

Tags: java, regex, stringtokenizer

Consider the following String:

```
String str = XFB_PART~,XFB_IDF~,XFB_MODE~0,XFB_LOCALITEM~,XFB_REMOTEITEM~,XFB_MSG~keep,/this/,comma,ASYNCHRONOUS~0,BROADCAST~0,XFB_LOCALAGT~,XFB_SUSER~,XFB_RUSER~,XFB_FILE_NAME~,XFB_SAPPL~,XFB_RAPPL~,XFB_IDA~,XFB_MAXDURATION~000000
```

The idea here is to use comma as delimiter but at the same time ignore commas that are separated by a backslash.

So when I do this:

```
propsToken = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
```

I should be receiving this as one of the tokens:

```
XFB_MSG~keep,this,comma  (because there was a backslash preceding it)
```

Here's what I did:

```
String str = XFB_PART~,XFB_IDF~,XFB_MODE~0,XFB_LOCALITEM~,XFB_REMOTEITEM~,XFB_MSG~keep,\this\,comma,ASYNCHRONOUS~0,BROADCAST~0,XFB_LOCALAGT~,XFB_SUSER~,XFB_RUSER~,XFB_FILE_NAME~,XFB_SAPPL~,XFB_RAPPL~,XFB_IDA~,XFB_MAXDURATION~000000


String strWithComma = "";


    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(str) && str.contains("\,")){

        strWithComma = Arrays.toString(str.split("(?<!\\)),"));
        propsToken = new StringTokenizer(strWithComma, "");
    } else {
        propsToken = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
    }
```

But the output is empty. Is my RegEx incorrect? I want it to split those tokens based on the delimiter "," except for those who have a backslash preceding the comma, I want them to be displayed again without the backslash but still with the coma.

Comment: So, by a backslash, or forward slash?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I really mean backslash, but I wrote the symbol of a forward slash. Let me fix it.

Comment: Then match them with `(?s)(?:\\.|[^\\,])++`. In Java, `"(?s)(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\,])++"`, like [here](https://regex101.com/r/IiaxA0/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it out.